# Makefile for gnuplot (Many figures) and latex integration

Tags: makefile, latex, gnuplot

Question: How do I get a makefile that can check an arbitrary number of *.eps and *.gp (gnuplot codes) and has a rule to build new *.eps and *.tex files from the newly edited *.gp files?

Goal:
Create a Makefile that checks if any of my chapters (*.tex), plots (*.eps, *.tex), or gnuplot codes (*.gp) have changed since last compile. Create a generic rule that executes necessary *.gp codes before compiling document.

EDIT: More details on GOAL: I would like Make to build Thesis.pdf but before doing so execute any `foo.gp` files that have been altered since the last build. the .gp files may be updated for a number of reasons including changing of an axis label, a legend entry, added data...

Background: I am writing my dissertation and intend to make use of both LaTex and GNUplot.  Due to the large number of figures it seems like a good call to put together a makefile that insures if any of my gnuplot codes (*.gp) are changed that the necessary codes are executed (and the unchanged *.gp codes are not) before compiling the latex document. I am using epslatex to generate *.eps and *.tex files (to be used with \input --- not standalone). If it's not abundantly clear from the sample code this is my first stab at a makefile.

EDIT: More details on GNUplot

`gnuplot foo.gp` produces `foo.eps` (includes all graphic portions of a plot) and `foo.tex` (a tex file that formats the figure and adds all necessary text). `foo.gp` is a script that builds a plot (much like plotting in MatLab or with MatPlotLib in python). The `foo.tex` file is used as `\intut{foo.tex}` in the latex figure environment. I will likely have in the neighborhood of 100figures that my advisor will no doubt have me edit to ad nauseum meaning I will be repeatedly be editing many different gnuplot scripts.

Dir structure:

Root Dir: ~/dissertation

Latex files Dir: ~/dissertation/text (this is also where my makefile currently is)

Gnuplot codes Dir: ~/dissertation/figures/gnuplot_codes

Gnuplot output Dir: ~/dissertation/figures/figs

Here is my code thus far:

```
PAPER=Thesis
CODES=$(wildcard ../figures/gnuplot_codes/*.gp) # list of all gnuplot scripts
EPSES=$(wildcard ../figures/figs/*.eps) # list of all eps files
FIGTEX=$(wildcard ../figures/figs/*.tex) # list of all associated tex files

all:    $(EPSES) $(FIGTEX) $(CODES) $(PAPER).pdf
        evince $(PAPER).pdf

# This is the line I can't figure out --- 
# if any of the gnuplot codes are updated it runs all of them
$(EPSES) $(FIGTEX):   $(CODES)
        gnuplot $(CODES)

# compiles the latex document using latexmk
$(PAPER).pdf:    $(PAPER).tex $(EPSES) $(FIGTEX) $(CODES)
        latexmk -latex="latex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make $<
        dvips $(PAPER).dvi -Ppdf
        ps2pdf $(PAPER).ps

# This catches any missing *.eps files thrown back from latexmk
# I feel like I should have a way of checking before 
# running $(PAPER).pdf rule 
../figures/figs/%.eps:    ../figures/gnuplot_codes/%.gp
          gnuplot $<

# same as the rule above but for *.tex
../figures/figs/%.tex:    ../figures/gnuplot_codes/%.gp
          gnuplot $<

# this cleans all the latex files
clean:
    latexmk -CA
```

Comment: A little background might be in order for those of us who don't know gnuplot. When you execute `gnuplot foo.gp`, it produces `foo.eps` and `foo.tex`, is that right? And do you want Make to rebuild `Thesis.pdf` if you *delete* `foo.gp`?

Comment: @Beta  Please see the EDIT comments above for details on your questions... Does this clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll start with the list of existing gp files:

```
CODES=$(wildcard ../figures/gnuplot_codes/*.gp)
```

So far, so good. This list tells us which gp files exist, and therefore which eps and tex files can be built. (We don't care which ones already exist.)

```
EPSES=$(patsubst ../figures/gnuplot_codes/%.gp,../figures/figs/%.eps, $(CODES))
FIGTEX=$(patsubst ../figures/gnuplot_codes/%.gp,../figures/figs/%.tex, $(CODES))
```

Now for the rule to run gnuplot and produce those files. The trouble with this version:

```
$(EPSES) $(FIGTEX):   $(CODES)
    gnuplot $(CODES)
```

is that it makes *all* gp files prerequisites of *every* eps and tex file; change one gp file, and you must rebuild everything. So get rid of it and replace it with a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
../figures/figs/%.eps ../figures/figs/%.tex: ../figures/gnuplot_codes/%.gp
    gnuplot $<
```

(I don't know how gnuplot knows where to put its output files; you didn't specify, so I'll assume you have that part worked out. If you're having trouble with that, I'll be happy to help.)

Now for the `Thesis.pdf` rule:

```
# compiles the latex document using latexmk
$(PAPER).pdf: $(PAPER).tex $(EPSES) $(FIGTEX)
    latexmk -latex="latex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make $<
    dvips $(PAPER).dvi -Ppdf
    ps2pdf $(PAPER).ps
```

I removed the prerequisite `$(CODES)` because it appears to be redundant. The recipe could probably be improved (and generalized to produce other pdf files) but hey, if it ain't broke...

Finally the rule that runs the show (and should come first, if you want it to be the default):

```
all: $(EPSES) $(FIGTEX) $(CODES) $(PAPER).pdf
    evince $(PAPER).pdf
```

Unless `evince` actually *uses* the gp, eps and tex files, we can do without those prequisites:

```
all: $(PAPER).pdf
    evince $<
```

Give all that a try.